# How to adjust brightness without adjusting the hardware brightness

Tags: brightness

Since my laptop LCD comes with PWM brightness controller, I would like to minimize the effect of flicker. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any software or package allows me to adjust the brightness without adjusting the hardware brightness. For eg, I would like to set my hardware brightness to maximum to avoid PWM flicker issue, meanwhile I can adjust the display brightness without adjusting the max. hardware brightness.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
xrandr --output <name> --brightness .75
```

Where:

- `<name>` is output name derived by using `xrandr` with no parameters.
- `.75` is brightness of 75%. Enter value with up to two decimals, ie 50.55

Comment: to get <name> run `xrandr --listmonitors`
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/344x1080/193+0+0  eDP-1
in this case <name> is eDP-1

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found an app known as desktop dimmer. It works wonder for me where I can set the hardware brightness to maximum and dim the screen without changing the hardware brightness, the flicker issue is gone after that. Here is the link to download desktop dimmer: [Desktop Dimmer Download Link](https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer/releases)